# How to add accessibility title to a new view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I have an iOS app where when the user does some sort of actions, i open a new view using a view controller.
I create the view dynamically and do not have it associated with a storyboard. 
The thing that i am trying to achieve is that, when the new view opens, I want voiceover to read out a description of the view. 
I am able to have voiceover read the description of the individual components of the view when selected but the title of the view is not being read out. 
I have tried using the following options to get the voiceover to work:

```swift
viewController.title = 'Title View'
viewController.accessibilityLabel = 'Title View'
viewController.accessibilityHint = 'Title View'
```

None of the above are read out when the view is opened.

Comment: Have you already looked through this resource? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Posts a notification to assistive applications.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post)
But from what I understand you could use this

```swift
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: nil)
```

This will notify that the screen is changed and therefore voiceover will pick up the first element on the new view. 
If you want it to pick a specific element then you can add that element in the argument parameter.